# mutli line plot with d3.js and JSON data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'd like to plot a multi line graph with d3.js.
I have following data, which I get from a database and convert to JSON.

```
{"items":["itemID01","itemID12","itemID14","itemID15","itemID16"],
 "alpha":{
    "xvalue":["itemID03","itemID12","itemID14","itemID16"],
    "yvalue":[0,0,0,0]},
 "beta":{
    "xvalue":["itemID03","itemID12","itemID16"],
    "yvalue":[0,2,0]},
 "gamma":{
    "xvalue":["itemID03","itemID12","itemID14","itemID16"],
    "yvalue":[9,10,8,9]},
 "delta":{
    "xvalue":["itemID12","itemID14","itemID16"],
    "yvalue":[2,0,2]},
 "epsilon":{
    "xvalue":["itemID12"],
    "yvalue":[3]}}
```

I got it to work with one line. When I adjusted it to multiple lines, it doesn't show any lines at all. The code is based on this tutorial by d3noob http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/adding-more-than-one-line-to-graph-in.html

This is my javascript code:

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangePoints([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")"); 

// get the JSON data
d3.json("getdata.php", function(error, data) {
    //console.log(data);
    x.domain(data.items);
    y.domain([0, d3.max(d3.values(data.gamma.yvalue))]); 
    // hardcoded for now, use d3.max(data, function(d) { return Math.max(d.alpha.yvalue, d.beta.yvalue, ...); })

    // get the array keys
    var keys = [];
    for (var key in data){
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(key) && key !== 'items') {
            keys.push(key);
        }
    }

    //console.log(keys);

    var valueline = [];
    var i = 0;
    keys.forEach(function(k) {
        valueline[i] = d3.svg.line()
        //.defined(function(d) { return (d.xvalue !== null); })
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.xvalue); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.yvalue); });

        // Add the valueline path.
        svg.append("path")    
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", valueline[i](data[k]));
        //console.log(data[k]);
        i++;
    });


    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(-10,0)")
        .call(yAxis);
});
```

I set up a jsfiddle with the code http://jsfiddle.net/5PcPU/

I tried different variations of having svg.append("path") in and out of the foreach loop and just one valueline element or an array. But nothing worked so far

My guess is that the error is  close to those lines

```
.x(function(d) { return x(d.xvalue); })
.y(function(d) { return y(d.yvalue); });
```

since if I try to do this, I don't get any output

```
.x(function(d) { 
     console.log('test'); 
     console.log(d.xvalue);
     return x(d.xvalue); })
```

Comment: A couple of things... You have a syntax error in `data`, the sample code you pasted is truncated, and you don't need to redefine your line generator function on each iteration of `keys`. It would also be much easier for people to help you if you created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) (or similar) example, illustrating the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your input. 
I added a missing " in `data`, and the `});` in the pasted code. I also set up a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5PcPU/. I thought I have define the line generator function for each array element of `keys`. I changed it in the jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could make it work by rearranging the json data. If I use an array of x AND y values instead  of one array for the x values and another one for the y values, it plots like I expect it to.
So the `data` looks like this:

```
{"items":["itemID01","itemID12","itemID14","itemID15","itemID16"],
 "alpha":[{"x":"itemID03","y":0},
          {"x":"itemID12","y":0},
          {"x":"itemID14","y":0},
          {"x":"itemID16","y":0}],
 "beta":[{"x":"itemID03","y":0},
          {"x":"itemID12","y":2},
          {"x":"itemID16","y":0}],
 "gamma":[{"x":"itemID03","y":9},
          {"x":"itemID12","y":10},
          {"x":"itemID14","y":8},
          {"x":"itemID16","y":9}],
 "delta":[{"x":"itemID12","y":2},
          {"x":"itemID14","y":0},
          {"x":"itemID16","y":2}],
 "epsilon":[{"x":"itemID12","y":3}]}
```